# Is it incorrect to write $\int f(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int f(t) dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the two continuous real functions $g:[a,b]\rightarrow [c,d]$ and $f:[c,d]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is it incorrect to write $\int f(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int f(t) dt$? Since the LHS and the RHS are function with different domains and codomains they cannot be equal (although this is not true for the Riemann integral). Am I correct? If so, how should the substitution formula to solve antiderivatives be written?

Comment: If you want to write it this way you should at least indicate that the right hand side really depends on $x$ to avoid confusion. One *could* for example do this by writing $\int f(g(x)) g'(x){\rm d}x = \left.\int f(t){\rm d}t\right|_{t = g(x)}$.

Comment: g and g' need to be continous for the formula to stand. Otherwise, you might create bogus result, whcih I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $t=g(x)$, what you have is correct. It is just a change of variables, but $t$ still depends on the $x$.

To avoid the confusion you are having, I prefer to write the substitution formula as follows, letting $F$ be a primitive of $f$, i.e. $F'=f$, then 
$$
\int f(g(x))g'(x) dx= F(g(x)) + C
$$
Avoiding then the explicit change to the $t$ variable.